# How to automatically remove an expired key from a set?

Tags: redis

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *

1) "trending_showrooms"
2) "trending_hashtags"
3) "trending_mints"

127.0.0.1:6379> sort trending_mints by *->id DESC LIMIT 0 12

1) "mint_14216"
2) "mint_14159"
3) "mint_14158"
4) "mint_14153"
5) "mint_14151"
6) "mint_14146"
```

The keys are expired but the keys are inside set. I have to remove the expire keys automatically in redis

Comment: "How to automatically remove an expired key from a set?" -  For clarification, are you wanting to expire an individual member within a set, or expire the set key and everything within it?

Comment: Yes i want to expire an individual member within a set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a TTL on individual members within the `SET`.

This blog post dives a bit deeper on the issue and provides a few workarounds.
https://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-create-and-expire-list-items-in-redis/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please ready this page entirely: https://redis.io/topics/notifications

Summing up, you must have a sentinel program listening to `PUB/SUB` messages, and you must alter the `redis.conf` file to enable **keyevent expire notifications**:

in `redis.conf`:

```
notify-keyspace-events Ex
```

> In order to enable the feature a non-empty string is used, composed of
>   multiple characters, where every character has a special meaning
>   according to the following table

```
E     Keyevent events, published with __keyevent@<db>__ prefix.
x     Expired events (events generated every time a key expires)
```

Then the sentinel program must listen to the channel `__keyevent@0__:del`, if your database is `0`. Change the database number if using any other than zero.

Then when you subscribe to the channel and receive the `key` which is expiring, you simply issue a `SREM trending_mints key` to remove it from the set.

**IMPORTANT**

> The expired events are generated when a key is accessed and is found
>   to be expired by one of the above systems, as a result there are no
>   guarantees that the Redis server will be able to generate the expired
>   event at the time the key time to live reaches the value of zero.
>
> If no command targets the key constantly, and there are many keys with
>   a TTL associated, there can be a significant delay between the time
>   the key time to live drops to zero, and the time the expired event is
>   generated.
>
> Basically expired events are generated when the Redis server deletes
>   the key and not when the time to live theoretically reaches the value
>   of zero.

So keys *will* be deleted due to expiration, but the notification *is not* guaranteed to occur in the moment TTL reaches zero.

*ALSO*, if your sentinel program misses the `PUB/SUB` message, well... that's it, you won't be notified another time! (this is also on the link above)

Comment: "The keys are expired but the keys are inside set" - I believe he is referring to the members within a set, not the keys themselves.

Comment: Hi @davissp14, I think he has a duplicated structure, one simple key for each set member, and these simple keys are set to expire (at least he could do it this way).